# C++ Bad return type?

Tags: c++, return

I'm getting two sets of errors in Visual Studio with the following class header...

EDIT: Sorry guys forgot to show that I have indeed included Window.

```
#include "Window.h"

class Spark
{
    public:

        Window& getWindow();    // #1
        Window *win;            // #2
 };
```

#1 has the following issues:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

#2 has a very similar story...

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

I'm new to C++, and so I probably screwed up. What I want to do with #1 is to return a reference to a Window object and with #2 I am attempting to create a pointer that will be set to a window object after this object is created (hence the reason I'm using a pointer).

After searching around and staring at this for a while, I can't see anything wrong with these two lines. it looks like VS is hung up on the return type, and essentially not getting it. Yet to my knowledge I constructed these declarations correctly.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know of any `Window` at that point.

Comment: How the `Window` is defined?

Comment: Where is `Window` defined?  Did you forget an `#include`?

Comment: By any chance `Windows.h` includes `Spark.h` directly or indirectly?

Comment: Ah it does! That's almost surely it. I'm embarrassed.

Comment: Could you show us the relevant parts of the `Window.h` too?

Comment: Naveen nailed it, "Windows.h" referenced "Spark.h"

Comment: You can solve this issue either by removing the circular dependency or by forward declaration. (I updated my post with this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me as if the type `Window`is not known. Include the headerfile where `Window` is declared and make sure that you are using the correct namespaces or use the fully qualified typenames.

**Update:**
In case of circular dependencies, you could either remove the dependency somehow or use a forward declaration to avoid such situations. Simply place a `class Window;` line before Spark's declaration:

```
class Window;

class Spark {
    Window *test;
}
```

Comment: I should have included this, Window is defined in another header and it is included, I've edited my post to show this.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of error usually appears because there is no declaration of `Window` in scope at the time you try to use it.

This could be caused by any number of problems, one of which may be a missing `#include`.

You can see the effect this has by compiling the following code (with `g++`):

```
//typedef int xyzzy;
int main(void) {
    xyzzy plugh;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is (take note of the last line):

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:3: error: 'xyzzy' was not declared in this scope
prog.cpp:3: error: expected `;' before 'plugh'
```

but, when you uncomment that first line, it compiles fine.

You need to declare `Window` before the point where you try to use it.

If, as you seem to indicate, you believe you *do* define `Window`, you need to check that. It may be that you've got the declaration inside an `#ifdef` that isn't active, or you include your files in a loop that prevents the correct declaration order or any number of other things.